# window.onload and window.beforeunload not working while trying to update and display a variable

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

So i want to increment a variable when a user loads my website, and decrease that variable when a user leaves.

The output I'm getting is: "Value is : undefined"

which makes sense if the variable wasn't being incremented and left undefined. This leads me to believe the onload and onbeforeload functions aren't being executed. HOWEVER, with this code, when a user leaves the website they are prompted with an alert which leads me to believe the functions are being executed while the variable isn't being increment or decreased for some reason.

I am testing the connections from my laptop using firefox and my raspberry pi using the default browser.

What i was expecting was the variable VisOn to increase by 1 when my laptop connects to the website and would display: "Value is : 2" when my pi and laptop are both connected.

the code is posted below:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var VisOn;


     function load()
        {
            VisOn = VisOn +1 ;
            return VisOn;
        }

     function leave()
        {
            VisOn = VisOn -1 ;
            return VisOn;
        }   



    window.onbeforeunload = leave;
    window.onload = load;


</script>

</head>

<style>
body {background-color: lightyellow}
h1 {color:blue}

</style>

<body>



   <form>


   <br>

   value is : 
     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(VisOn)
      </script>

    </form>

    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to initialize the variable `VisOn`

```
var VisOn = 0;
```

Do it like this and it should work.

UPDATE: Added the working jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qept46bo/

Comment: when i give it a value, the output is: "Value is : 0" and when i load the website on my laptop the output is still: "Value is : 0" it should be 1 if my code works correctly or it would ideally be 2

Comment: That's because you are not updating the html element to reflect the new value of `VisOn`. You incremented the value for the variable inside onload function, but that doesn't repaint the DOM element. You need to manually update the element.
here is a  working jsfiddle in action
https://jsfiddle.net/qept46bo/

Comment: this works, however, when i have two ip's connected to the website, it still only displays 1, i think this is because we set the VisOn var to 0 every time the script is ran, i changed it back to "var VisOn;" instead of "var VisOn = 0" but all that did was output: "value is NaN", any ideas on how to have this work for multiple connections and count how many connects are live?

Comment: One thing to note here is that we are just storing the visit count on the client-side. Basically what it means that it wouldn't persist after reloads or if it's being accessed from another computer.
If you want to implement a true visit counter, you should save it in a database and persist the data.

Comment: Where have you initialized the VisOn = 0 in the script ?

Answer (score 0):

besides the missing initialization already mentioned above, there is no mechanism added, that can retrieve the amount of other people opening the page.
Your javascript is running ONLY on the client, meaning you need to add some server communication to have the intended effect.